# Is there any way to hide current location and jdk loaction?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Every time when I run java code on `VScode` it showing very long java path location, so want to hide this java path location. This long path hide actually what happening to `VSCode`.

Example `cd /home/anindra/Documents/oppsClass ; /usr/bin/env /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /home/anindra/Documents/oppsClass/bin App`  to `/home/anindra/Documents/oppsClass/bin App`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb2nX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to remove or hide these execution scripts in integrated **Terminal**, but we have some workarounds:

1. In [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configure), set `"console": "internalConsole",`. Then **Run without Debugging**, the result will be shown in **Debug Console** and no execution scripts: [image]
2. In `launch.json`, set `"console": "externalTerminal",`. Then **Run without Debugging**, the result will be shown in **external Terminal** and no execution scripts:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You are in a terminal inside VS Code and launching a Java application.

- cd `cd ...` command can be skipped imho as you are already inside the `Documents/oppsClass` directory.
- Typically you have a the `java` executable on your `PATH`, so no need to specify the full path `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`
- You can also paste the lines you want to hide into shell script and execute this one.